# Turn off GPS programmatically when i exit my program

Tags: android, gps

I have started my GPS programmatically by
Intent myIntent = new intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
mContext.startActivity(myIntent);

How i will turn Off GPS when i exit from my program...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(myLocationListener);
locationManager = null;
```

This will shut down GPS for this app, but it is still available for use by other apps.

Be sure to test your app on a real phone because the emulator does not show the same GPS behavior as a real phone.