# Android turn on GPS and Internet

Tags: android, gps

How to turn on GPS and Internet on Android, with code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically enable GPS in Android Cupcake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051649/how-to-programmatically-enable-gps-in-android-cupcake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the user interaction that I have seen, I would say the preferred way to do this is simply to **prompt the user** to turn on GPS if it is off. This is totally speculation though.

See also:

- [Turn off GPS programmatically when i exit my program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306984/turn-off-gps-programmatically-when-i-exit-my-program)
- [How to programmatically enable GPS in Android Cupcake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051649/how-to-programmatically-enable-gps-in-android-cupcake).