# Android: How to prevent GPS auto-disable

Tags: android, gps

We created a small app, that tells your location. On some devices, if there is no signal to gps satellites (in a house, tunnel, underground) it is searching for a while, then it stops and never searches again. So it is disables automatically after some time. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi check this post for enabling and disable the gps programmtically hope you get some idea/help

[How can I enable or disable the GPS programmatically on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker/5305835#5305835)

[How to programmatically enable GPS in Android Cupcake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051649/how-to-programmatically-enable-gps-in-android-cupcake/1051827#1051827)

[Turn off GPS programmatically when i exit my program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306984/turn-off-gps-programmatically-when-i-exit-my-program/3307780#3307780)

Comment: I can enable/disable a gps programmatically. The problem is, that if it has no satellite signal, it turns off, and never tries to connect to satellites again.

Comment: @McDermott, Pratik probably tried to say that you could just reenable GPS once it was disabled / had lost all the satellite signals. I don't know whether it helps to find the lost signals or not.